# What path to put inside .getResource()

Tags: java

[Java]
I am having trouble figuring which String to put inside variable s below.

```
return new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(s));
```

I do know that I need to put the path here, but I don't know the format.
This is the full path of the image I am trying to import (which didn't work):

Users/Kevin1031/eclipse-workspace/B-Tring/bin/textures/Center_Ring_0.png

I am using Mac OS, and B-Tring is the project folder, textures is the package, and Center_Ring_0.png is the image I want to import and use.

So, can someone tell me what path to put in?

Comment: The resource needs to be part of your project's source.  "/src/my/package/Center_Ring_0.png" or something like that.  If you don't do that it basically can't work.

Comment: So the resource should be in the project folder?

Comment: Yes, basically.  It should be in a Java package (i.e., the directory the package uses).  Access it by that package name (with slashes like I showed) followed by its own filename.  If you don't put it in the source tree, then it isn't really a "resource" and you should access it with the `File` class instead.

Comment: Oh, but my example used "/src" as the start of the path.  Don't do that.  For a resource path like that, just use "/my/package/Center_Ring_0.png".  Also it's standard to put the resource in the same package (directory) as the class that uses it, and just load the resource as `getResource("Center_Ring_0.png")` which with no leading slash will default to the same packages as the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first try the full absolute path with / at the beginning
`/Users/Kevin1031/eclipse-workspace/B-Tring/bin/textures/Center_Ring_0.png`

I don't know about Eclipse, I work in IntelliJ, where if you cofigure a folder as "resources" in the module settings, you can reference from there. f.e. if you would set bin/ as resourcer the path would be `/textures/Center_Ring_0.png`.

Third option is to use a relative path. f.e. if you call the method from `B-Tring/src/foo.java` try something like `../textures/Center_Ring_0.png`. Notice not starting with the slash